# how implement cross validation with flower dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, cross-validation, transfer-learning

the dataset contains 3670 images in 5 folders ['daisy', 'dandelion', 'roses', 'sunflowers', 'tulips']
i want to use vgg16 or any model and Cross-Validation to improve my accuracy, right now it's between 84-86%.

Comment: I think more details are needed like what parameters have you done already. How much accuracy do you get during your training,  What is the size of the training and validation set. Likewise, there can be multiple paths you can follow to increase your cross-validation accuracy, for example, improve the size of the data-set (including training, validation, and test set).  You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: thank you very much for the replay this this is my first question in stackoverflow.I'm a noob in this field, i have tested transfer learning models with the flower dataset, i read some article about cross validation and i want to test it with this dataset. but the dataset does not contain csv file.

Comment: Please share just a snapshot of the df so that we can get some knowledge of your data structure and what code you run to do the cross-valdidation. See guidlines [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.